# how to check if django query success

Tags: django

when I use django query .
I will use `.exists` to check if it is success. like:

```
que = Image.objects.filter(id=1)        
if que.exists():    
    #do something
```

I want to ask if I use `update` like this:

`Image.objects.filter(id=ac[0].id).update(url=image['url'],path=image['path'])`

how can I check the query is success??

please guide me . Thank you

Answer (score 4):

from the [orm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

> The update() method is applied instantly and returns the number of
>   rows matched by the query (which may not be equal to the number of
>   rows updated if some rows already have the new value).

Also, it is important to note that calling `update` is an atomic operation. so if it does not succeed, it will raise an error.

if you are sure that the update should modify at least one row, do

```
num = Image.objects.filter(id=ac[0].id).update(url=image['url'],path=image['path'])
if num > 0:
    print "successful
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the query to a variable like:

```
try:
   img = Image.objects.filter(id=ac[0].id).update(url=image['url'],path=image['path'])
   img[0]
   print "success"
except:
   print "failed"
```